# C# Entity Framework Core Conditional Projection

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-core, projection

I currently use Entity Framework Core, and it works really well. However, one things I am trying to optimise in my application is returning computed data from the database at the time of querying. I am using code first, where each model directly maps to a single table in.

Here is a simplified example of my persistence models:

```cs
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserRole> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class UserRole
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public User User { get; set; }

    public string Role { get; set; }
}
```

What I am currently using is a variation on the specification pattern which enables me to run a variable amount of `.Include / .ThenInclude` on the query before executing. However, what I want to be able to do is conditionally enable specific parts of a projection.

For example, here is how my domain models might appear:

```cs
public class UserImpl
{
    public User User { get; set; }

    public int? RoleCount { get; set; }

    public static Expression<Func<User, UserImpl>> Projection(UserImplParams opts) {
        return u => new UserImpl
        {
            User = u,
            RoleCount = opts != null && opts.IncludeRoleCount ? u.Roles.Count() : default(int?)
        };
    }
}

public class UserImplParams
{
    public bool IncludeRoleCount { get; set; }
}
```

And what I would like to achieve is a way to do something similar to this:

```cs
var opts= new UserImplParams
{
    IncludeUserRole = true
};

await _databaseContext.Users.Select(UserImpl.Projection(opts)).ToListAsync();
```

I would like it so that EF Core EITHER sees:

```cs
u => new UserImpl
{
    User = u,
    RoleCount = u.Roles.Count()
};
```

OR

```cs
u => new UserImpl
{
    User = u,
    RoleCount = default(int?)
};
```

Is that possible? This is mainly because this expression could contain several projection properties, and even nested ones. Firing the whole thing to the database every time for only a handful of data seems inefficient.

Comment: lots of detail here, but I'm not following. i get that you conditionaly trying to say as to where to include or not but the logic all completely (WIP). first how did you get an instance of UserImpl, and what is UserImplParams. basically i would say "no", you are mixing lots of things as once here. Just have separate logical calls for the one which should include and other which shouldn't.

Comment: I've updated the question, it's mostly irrelevant what `UserImplParams` is but added for completeness. The idea is how can I construct a dynamic expression? Will I need to implement an expression visitor?

Comment: you should look into GraphQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT] I have posted a much more up to date version of this code on my website
https://eliottrobson.me/entity-framework-core-projection-performance/
It is basically the same, but adds support for more scenarios.

---

The reason I wanted to do this was partly due to premature optimisation. I am sure, in 90% of circumstances sending a massive SQL with CASE WHEN 1=1 or 1=0 (for true and false) will be optimised correctly. However, it's a fact that CASE statements don't always short circuit https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/12941/does-sql-server-read-all-of-a-coalesce-function-even-if-the-first-argument-is-no/12945#12945.

Without further ado, here is my solution on how this can be achieved.

The main functionality lies within this new class:

```cs
public class ProjectionExpressionVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    internal Expression<Func<TSource, TDest>> Optimise<TSource, TDest>(Expression<Func<TSource, TDest>> expression)
    {
        return Visit(expression) as Expression<Func<TSource, TDest>>;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitConditional(ConditionalExpression node)
    {
        var test = ReduceExpression(node.Test);

        // The conditional is now a constant, we can replace the branch
        if (test is ConstantExpression testNode)
        {
            var value = (dynamic) testNode.Value;
            return value ? ReduceExpression(node.IfTrue) : ReduceExpression(node.IfFalse);
        }

        // If it is not a conditional, we follow the default behaviour
        return base.VisitConditional(node);
    }

    public Expression ReduceExpression(Expression node)
    {
        if (node is ConstantExpression)
        {
            // Constants represent the smallest item, so we can just return it
            return node;
        }
        else if (node is MemberExpression memberNode)
        {
            return ReduceMemberExpression(memberNode);
        }
        else if (node is BinaryExpression binaryNode)
        {
            return ReduceBinaryExpression(binaryNode);
        }

        // This is not a supported expression type to reduce, fallback to default
        return node;
    }

    public Expression ReduceMemberExpression(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (
            node.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant ||
            node.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess
        )
        {
            var objectMember = Expression.Convert(node, typeof(object));
            var getterLambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<object>>(objectMember);
            var getter = getterLambda.Compile();
            var value = getter();

            return Expression.Constant(value);
        }

        return node;
    }

    public Expression ReduceBinaryExpression(BinaryExpression node)
    {
        var left = ReduceExpression(node.Left);
        var right = ReduceExpression(node.Right);

        var leftConst = left as ConstantExpression;
        var rightConst = right as ConstantExpression;

        // Special optimisations
        var optimised = OptimiseBooleanBinaryExpression(node.NodeType, leftConst, rightConst);
        if (optimised != null) return Expression.Constant(optimised);

        if (leftConst != null && rightConst != null)
        {
            var leftValue = (dynamic)leftConst.Value;
            var rightValue = (dynamic)rightConst.Value;

            switch (node.NodeType)
            {
                case ExpressionType.Add:
                    return Expression.Constant(leftValue + rightValue);
                case ExpressionType.Divide:
                    return Expression.Constant(leftValue / rightValue);
                case ExpressionType.Modulo:
                    return Expression.Constant(leftValue % rightValue);
                case ExpressionType.Multiply:
                    return Expression.Constant(leftValue * rightValue);
                case ExpressionType.Power:
                    return Expression.Constant(leftValue ^ rightValue);
                case ExpressionType.Subtract:
                    return Expression.Constant(leftValue - rightValue);
                case ExpressionType.And:
                    return Expression.Constant(leftValue & rightValue);
                case ExpressionType.AndAlso:
                    return Expression.Constant(leftValue && rightValue);
                case ExpressionType.Or:
                    return Expression.Constant(leftValue | rightValue);
                case ExpressionType.OrElse:
                    return Expression.Constant(leftValue || rightValue);
                case ExpressionType.Equal:
                    return Expression.Constant(leftValue == rightValue);
                case ExpressionType.NotEqual:
                    return Expression.Constant(leftValue != rightValue);
                case ExpressionType.GreaterThan:
                    return Expression.Constant(leftValue > rightValue);
                case ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual:
                    return Expression.Constant(leftValue >= rightValue);
                case ExpressionType.LessThan:
                    return Expression.Constant(leftValue < rightValue);
                case ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual:
                    return Expression.Constant(leftValue <= rightValue);
            }
        }

        return node;
    }

    private bool? OptimiseBooleanBinaryExpression(ExpressionType type, ConstantExpression leftConst, ConstantExpression rightConst)
    {
        // This is only a necessary optimisation when only part of the binary expression is constant
        if (leftConst != null && rightConst != null)
            return null;

        var leftValue = (dynamic)leftConst?.Value;
        var rightValue = (dynamic)rightConst?.Value;

        // We can check for constants on each side to simplify the reduction process
        if (
            (type == ExpressionType.And || type == ExpressionType.AndAlso) &&
            (leftValue == false || rightValue == false))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else if (
            (type == ExpressionType.Or || type == ExpressionType.OrElse) &&
            (leftValue == true || rightValue == true))
        {
            return true;
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Fundamentally, the idea is that we optimise conditional expressions through reducing them as much as possible and then apply some special case logic when mixing parameter lambdas.

Usage is as follows

```cs
var opts = new UserImplParams
{
    IncludeUserRole = true
};

var projection = UserImpl.Projection(opts);

var expression = new ProjectionExpressionVisitor().Optimise(projection);

await _databaseContext.Users.Select(expression).ToListAsync();
```

Hopefully this will help someone else with a similar problem.

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score -1):

you can change group name conditionally first(in the first select) and then group again,
now that you have two types of groups

```
            .GroupBy(x => new {x.Brand})
            .Select(x => new DisputeReportListModel
            {
                Amount = x.Sum(y => y.Amount),
                Scheme = _isMastercard(x.Key.Brand) ? "MASTERCARD" : "VISA",
            }).AsEnumerable()
            .GroupBy(x => new {x.Scheme})
            .Select(x => new DisputeReportListModel
            {
                Amount = x.Sum(y => y.Amount),
                Scheme = x.Key.Scheme
            })
            .ToList();
```